# Image/text positions?

Tags: graphics, positioning

tl;dr I need to shift a line of text down below an image, how do I do that?

I have two sets of images and descriptions for them, but they aren't appearing in order; instead, they're showing up in the following order:

Description 1,
Description 2,
Image 1,
Image 2

rather than Description 1, Image 1, Description 2, Image 2

The code is here:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Begin subsection}
\noindent
- Point 1 under the first description\\
- Point 2 under the first description\\
\begin{figure}[htp]
\raggedleft %note: there's going to be another image next to this later
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{firstimage}
\end{figure}
Second description\\
\begin{figure}[htp]
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{secondimage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

All of this is on one page, so that can't be the issue. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You don't HAVE to use the figure environment, which is specifically intended to move images around (float).  Second if you intend to put two images side-by-side, you need to do it immediatesly.  Use \hfil to put space in front of and between then.

Comment: 1. How can I use the MWE package?

Comment: 2. What alternative to the figure environment would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following if it works for you:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,mwe}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Begin subsection}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\raggedleft %note: there's going to be another image next to this later
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}\\
\noindent
- Point 1 under the first description\\
- Point 2 under the first description\\
\end{figure} 
\begin{figure}[htp]
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}\\
Second description\\
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that I included the `mwe` package.

I also had to change the width of the images since their combined width (10 + 13 cm) is greater than the width of a letter-sized paper (21.59 cm).

I got the following output:

[image: myoutput]